# How to animate drawing a sequence of line segments

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to draw a point and after 1 sec or so I would like to draw the next point. Is this somehow possible:

I already tried:

```
function simulate(i) {
  setTimeout(function() { drawPoint(vis,i,i); }, 1000);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 200; ++i)
  simulate(i);

function drawPoint(vis,x,y){
  var svg = vis.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      console.log(x);
      return 700/2+x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return 700/2+y;
    })
   .attr("r", function(d) {
     console.log(x);
     return 6;
   });
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. It just draws the whole line immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work, because the for loop will immediately run to the end, the setTimeouts will be scheduled simultaneously and all the functions will fire at the same time.

Instead of that, do this:

```
var i = 1;
(function loop(){
    if(i++ > 200) return;
    setTimeout(function(){
        drawPoint(vis,i,i); 
        loop()
    }, 1000)
})();
```

**Explanation:**

This IIFE will run for the first time with `i = 1`. Then, the `if` increases `i` (doing `i++`) and checks if it is bigger than 200. If it is, the function `loop` returns. If it's not, a `setTimeout` is scheduled, which calls `drawnPoint` and the very function `loop` again.

Comment: instead of `simulate(i);`  `drawPoint(vis,i,i)`

Comment: 这是太棒了。 Thanks this is aweasome!